# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE to OPEN

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-12c

I'm currently working with Oracle database version 12c. I have created a common admin user - "C##ADMIN" with DBA Role. But when trying to execute the following script:

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE TESTPDB OPEN;
```

I hit error:

> ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege

How should I assign the correct roles/privileges to "C##ADMIN" in order to run script above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grant `SYSDBA`/`DBA` privilege to the user to all containers and login as `SYSDBA` to perform the task.

Demo:

```
SQL> create user c##admin identified by c##admin container=all;

User created.

SQL> grant sysdba to c##admin container=all;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn c##admin as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> alter pluggable database orclpdb open;
```

Answer (score 0):

[ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2008.htm#SQLRF55667)

> To specify the `pdb_change_state` clause, the current container must be
>   the PDB whose state you want to change and you **must be authenticated
>   `AS SYSBACKUP`, `AS SYSDBA`, `AS SYSDG`, or `AS SYSOPER`.**
>
> To specify the `pdb_change_state_from_root` clause, the current
>   container must be the root, you **must be authenticated `AS SYSBACKUP`, `AS
>   SYSDBA`, `AS SYSDG`, or `AS SYSOPER`, and the `SYSBACKUP`, `SYSDBA`, `SYSDG`, or
>   `SYSOPER` privilege must be either granted to you commonly**, or granted
>   to you locally in the root and locally in the PDB(s) whose state(s)
>   you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

connect to your pluggable database:

```
CONN system/syspasss@//localhost:1521/pluggableDBname

create user marcopolo identified by marco9274 container=current;
```

You cannot create a local role with container=ALL. It doesn’t work, so use

```
container=current
```

Than you can do

```
grant sysdba to marcopolo container=current;
```

connect as that user

```
conn marcopolo as sysdba
```

And do your mojo now.